# How to improve performance of loading a lot of records to WPF dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, performance

I'm new to WPF application. I have built an application what connect to online database that mean i host my database on the hosting server (SQL Server) and my WPF applicaiton running locally.

I have more than 1000 records of item when i open my application those record will be loaded in to a combobox. The problem is it spend more than 5minutes to load those records. Does anyone know any other way to make it faster?

Comment: What did you profile so far? Which part is slow? [Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx)? [Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Is it WPF which is slow or your database? I suspect it's latter so you need to improve on that side. To test, try loading 10 and 100 records instead of all 1000 and see how it affects the performance.

Comment: Side note: 1000 items in combobox/dropdown/list are generally unusable from UI point of view... Make sure you really need all of them to be loaded directly (and if you don't have unbound number of items there).

Answer (score 6):

the `ComboBox` does not have [UI Virtualization](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Virtualization.html) enabled by default.

The reason for this is that the `ComboBox` is not really intended to show a large number of items.

To enable it, change the [`ItemsPanel`](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/02/10/itemscontrol-p-is-for-panel/):

```
<ComboBox ...>
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
           <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

Keep in mind, however, that showing more than even 20 items in a `ComboBox` will result in a really painful User Experience.

You should really consider changing to a `ListBox` or other type of UI element more suitable for displaying large lists of items.